# Access Authorisation check in microservices architecture

Tags: microservices

Assume we have following services

- **Service A**: Check whether a given user has valid subscription
- **Service B**: A feature that only subscribed users can access

If an user accesses **service B**, it somehow has to check whether the user is subscribed or not and therefore, it will access **service A**. I learnt that the communications between microservices should be asynchronous so they are loosely coupled. How can I achieve above?

One idea is to use **JWT**, but what if the **Service A** returns a long list (a list of thousands of ownership permissions) that using JWT isn't practical?

Comment: Have you find a solution?